# Running http-proxy in a VM and redirect HOST OS through that proxy

Tags: virtualbox

I am running a HTTP-PROXY in a VirtualBox VM. 
I am exposeing the HTTP_PROXY on `port 8005`. 
I can successfully redirect requests through that proxy in the GUEST OS.
I am running a Windows10 as a guest.

I connected the GUEST and HOST OS via NAT with port-redirect.
I am redirecting `port 8005`.

I do run more software on different ports in VM, which I can reach from the HOST.

Somehow, when configuring the system-proxy `127.0.0.1:8005`
it has no effect.

Any ideas, why?